# Google Big Query + PHP -> How to fetch a large data set without running out of memory

Tags: php, sql, memory, google-bigquery, large-data

I am trying to run a query in BigQuery/PHP (using google php SDK) that returns a large dataset (can be 100,000 - 10,000,000 rows).

```
$bigqueryService = new Google_BigqueryService($client);

$query = new Google_QueryRequest();
$query->setQuery(...);

$jobs = $bigqueryService->jobs;
$response = $jobs->query($project_id, $query); 
//query is a syncronous function that returns a full dataset
```

The next step is to allow the user to download the result as a CSV file.

The code above will fail when the dataset becomes too large (memory limit).
What are my options to perform this operation with lower memory usage ?

(I figured an option is to save the results to another table with BigQuery and then start doing partial fetch with LIMIT and OFFSET but I figured a better solution might be available..)

Thanks for the help

Comment: I would avoid using php for such a task if possible in any way. Otherwise you could split the query in some subqueries with a smaller limit and append it to the csv file step by step.

Comment: @Johnny000 What language would be better suited for this? Thanks

Comment: I used alot of Java with such amount of datasets, had some very similar amounts of data. But if you read a CSV file from google line by line as mentioned in the answers, it should also work out great in php as for my part I only made good experience when it comes to php and csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion to export is a good one, I just wanted to mention there is another way.

The query API you are calling (`jobs.query()`) does not return the full dataset; it just returns a page of data, which is the first 2 MB of the results. You can set the `maxResults` flag (described [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query)) to limit this to a certain number of rows.

If you get back fewer rows than are in the table, you will get a `pageToken` field in the response. You can then fetch the remainder with the `jobs.getQueryResults()` API by providing the job ID (also in the query response) and the page token. This will continue to return new rows and a new page token until you get to the end of your table.

The example [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#syncqueries) shows code (in java in python) to run a query and fetch the results page by page.

There is also an option in the API to convert directly to CSV by specifying `alt='csv'` in the URL query string, but I'm not sure how to do this in PHP.

Comment: As it turns out, this is exactly what I did :) 

It is worth noting that in order to use this you need to run the job as an ASYNC job using $jobs->insert rather than the $jobs->query which returns a full dateset.

After using the Insert you should use the $jobs->get(PROJ_ID, $jobId) to query the state of the job periodically until it is in state 'DONE'.

After that you can use the $jobs->getQueryResults(PROJECT_ID, $jobId, $params) to grab N lines from X offset. (Note you also have to use the pageToken when grabbing partially as Jordan said)

Comment: Actually jobs.query() really shouldn't return more than 2MB of data... I've reproduced the issue and filed internal bug.

Answer (score 4):

You can export your data directly from Bigquery

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery

You can use PHP to run a API call that does the export (you dont need the BQ tool)

You need to set the jobs `configuration.extract.destinationFormat` see the [reference](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#exporting)

Comment: So essentially do this:
Run the query and write into a table with the results.
Run extract outside of PHP (using BQ tool?)
Process said results file

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Wouldn't running this export-csv-command via the PHP use the memory inside PHP ?

Comment: No, it's an asynchronous job, you just submit the meta data, and the job will be executed on their server.

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on Pentium10's answer

You can export up to a 1GB file in json format.
Then you can read the file line by line which will minimize the memory used by your application and then you can use `json_decode` the information.

Comment: There is a wildcard character that supports exporting to multiple files. And anyway you need to read the file line by line.

Comment: @Pentium10 yes I know for bigger files - I just wanted to append more to your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure do you still using the PHP but the answer is:

```php
$options = [
    'maxResults' => 1000,
    'startIndex' => 0
];

$jobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($jobConfig, $options);

foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
    // Handle rows
}
```